# Remove blank space in hist3D

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I'd like to remove the yellow information and blank space outside green squared in figure.

[image]

```
x <- matrix(runif(10000), ncol = 100)
plot3D::hist3D(z=x/sum(x))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hist3D` has a set of parameters to control the color key,  including whether or not to plot it at all. You can get rid of the extra whitespace using the graphics parameter `mar`.

```
x <- matrix(runif(10000), ncol = 100)
par(mar=rep(0,4))
plot3D::hist3D(z=x/sum(x), colkey=list(plot=FALSE))
```

[image: No color key]